# What type of object does Reporting Services use to pass multiple rows to custom aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ssrs-2008, aggregate-functions

Assume the following dataset:

```
declare
    @datesTest table(dateId date, someValue int)
insert into
    @datesTest 
values
    ('01/01/2013', 15),
    ('01/01/2013', 15),
    ('02/01/2013', 0),
    ('03/01/2013', 27),
    ('03/01/2013', 27),
    ('03/01/2013', 27),
    ('04/01/2013', 44),
    ('04/01/2013', 44),
    ('05/01/2013', 0)

/* data is in this format with about 15 other fields that make distinct at this level not viable */
select
    *
from
    @datesTest;

/* not the average I want */
select
    avg(someValue) incorrectAvg
from
    @datesTest;

/* the average I do want (avg of distinct) */
select
    avg(_1.someValue) correctAvg
from
(
    select distinct
        *
    from
        @datesTest
)_1
```

Also assume that there is nothing I can do change the dataset or manipulate fields in SQL.

From Reporting Services, I would like to create a custom function that accepts these values in some form, removes duplicates, and then returns a true average.

The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure what type of object SSRS uses to pass multiple rows to custom functions.

Comment: What version of SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a dataset that references another data set.

Create dataset ParentList. This will be your filter dataset. You should return only one value column and you should be able to pull this list from your original dataset (the one with duplicate rows). You only need to pull the values you are averaging.
Create a new report parameter called ParentList. Set both the available values and the default values to the value column result from the dataset ParentList. Set the parameter to Hidden.
Create a second dataset RealAverage (or whatever). Add ParentList as a parameter to dataset RealAverage, called @ParentList.

In the child query, use the parameter like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(my column) WHERE valueColumn IN (@ParentList)
```

This will return unique rows, which you can then use the standard SSRS Avg

It's not very clean, but it should do the trick. Play around with creating parameters from datasets, and keep in mind a parameter can only be made from a dataset with one row.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  Let me tinker with this for a bit, and if it works I'll mark it as correct.